# is it safe to browse in other browser while using TOR browser?

Tags: security

I'm a new user so I wanted to confirm if browsing simultaneously on some other browser will affect my security .

Comment: Safe against what? Secure against what? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Anonymity for my location as I don't want my ISP to know what I'm surfing but I usually like to browse on my chrome along with TOR browser.

Answer (score 0):

The only extra risk here would be that you might get confused about which browser you're in and accidentally login to a site over clearnet that you meant to login to over tor. Otherwise simultaneous regular browsing should not effect the security of your tor browsing at all.